# angular Filter to display onlychild checkboxes matching parent name

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I am having a problem getting this working properly...at least in a way that works well.

I have parent checkboxes and children checkboxes being fed from an array of objects.

```
$scope.parents = [
    {name: 'check1', value: 'ck1'},
    {name: 'check2', value: 'ck2'}
];

$scope.children = [
    {name: 'child1', value' ch1', parent: 'ck1'},
    {name: 'child2', value: 'ch2', parent 'ck2'}
];
```

I can get this working but the issue is in some cases I have 8 children, and currently I am hiding any checkboxes that are not for the right parents, but they still show up on the DOM, meaning there is a huge space between parent checkboxes, even when nothing is checked.  I have tried using an ng-if instead of ng-hide, but that doesn't work either, they still show up the same.  It functions properly, only children that match the parent value show up, but they are still in the DOM and taking up space on the screen even when not viewable.

So I wanted to see if there is a way using angular filters that I can do this, but I haven't been able to get it to work...

I have tried

```
ng-repeat="parent in parents track by $index"
...<checkbox>...
ng-repeat="child in children | filter: {'parent': {{parent.value}}} track by $index" 
...<checkbox>...
```

but this doesn't work properly, I get an error...basically I need to compare the 'parent' property in children to the parent.value of the parent checkbox...is there a way to do this via the filter method I am using?  If not is there an easy way for only the elements that are matching to show up underneath the parents and not all of the elements?

Ideally you would have very little space between the checkboxes until a parent is selected and then the children would be added and it would make room for them by adjusting the others downward...

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rather simpler way of dealing with things is to have a ng-if within the nested ng-repeat.

```
<div ng-repeat="parent in parents">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedParent[parent.value]" value="parent.value"/>
        <span ng-bind="parent.name"></span>
    </label>
    <div ng-repeat="child in children" ng-if="selectedParent[child.parent] && child.parent === parent.value">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedChild[child.value]" value="child.value"/>
            <span ng-bind="child.name"></span>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

The above code will make sure that

- the children elements appear only if the parent is selected
- other unnecessary elements are not created by Angularjs
- There is no unnecessary space between checkbox elements
- This will work irrespective of the number of children for a given parent

Comment: Fantastic stuff!  Works like a charm

Comment: @MattE: Happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom filter to check checked status of parent checkboxes and display child checkboxes accordingly

js

```
  $scope.myCustomFilter = function(row){
    var flag = false;
    angular.forEach($scope.parents, function(value, key){
        if(value.checked){
          if(value.value == row.parent)
            flag = true;
        }
    });

    return flag;
  }
```

html

```
<div ng-repeat ="item in parents">
   <input type="checkbox" ng-value="item.value" ng-model="item.checked"> {{item.name}}
</div>
<div ng-repeat ="item in children | filter: myCustomFilter">
   <input type="checkbox" ng-value="item.value"> {{item.name}}-Parent: {{item.parent}}
</div>
```

[**Demo**](https://plnkr.co/edit/R8YgiB8HEHuALC4JjZdP?p=preview)